# Merge sort python 3

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I implemented such merge sorting algorithm, hoverer I got some issues

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
        input = sys.stdin.read()
        data = list(map(int, input.split()))
        n = data[0]
        a = data[1:]
        print(merge_sort(a))

def merge(left,rigt):
    result = []
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(rigt):
        if left[i] <= rigt[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1

        else:
            result.append(rigt[j])
            j += 1

    result += left[i:]
    result += rigt[j:]

    return result

def merge_sort(a):
    if len(a) <= 2:
        return 1

    middle = len(a)//2

    left = a[:middle]
    right = a[middle:]

    left = merge_sort(left)
    right = merge_sort(right)

    return list(merge(left,right))
```

I got such error

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I can't understand, where I went wrong, why program thinks that "left" and "right" are int, however it is array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace

```
if len(a) <= 2:
    return 1
```

with

```
if len(a) == 1:
    return a
```

to return a list which is not partitionable.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the terminating case of your merge_sort function, which returns 1. Thus, left and rigt are int when the recursion reaches the bottom, and you need to take account for that in your code.